# Cannot access DOM for cleanup in the react useEffect return function on Component Unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, removeeventlistener

I have the following component and am attaching an eventlistner to the button present in it by DOM manipulation. I can confirm that the eventListener is attached as when the button is clicked i can see a console log in the devtools.The issue here is i cannot remove the eventListener in the return fucntion as i have done below. Most of the blogs and guidebooks out there suggest using the useRef hook. I am familiar with the useRef hook and Yes it does work.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyCustomComponent() {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Define the event handler
    function handleClick() {
      console.log('Button was clicked!');
    }
    
    document.getElementById("uniqueId").addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    // Cleanup: remove the event listener from the button
    return () => {
      document.getElementById("uniqueId").removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []); // The empty dependency array means this useEffect will run once after the component is mounted

  return (
    <div>
      <button id="uniqueId">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyCustomComponent;
```

The above is a minified version the problem i am facing and not the actual exact case.
Due to some specific requirement i am serving a pure JS file in my project and trying to append HTML Nodes, to the component using my Javscript code using dom manipulation(in this case imagine i am appending the button#uniqueId with dom manipulation), which is working fine for me.

But when i go onto provid a cleanup fucntion and try to removeEventListener in the cleanup function, I cannot access the DOM elements and it is adding to the Detached Nodes Count for the webpage in the DevTools. This problem will add up to the load onthe page and potential memory Leaks for the webpage. Why does react documentation suggest that any cleanup can be performed in the return fucntion when we cannot even access the dom in it.

For any furthur clarifications on the question, please comment.

Comment: Your currently rendering the button in React, so where is the custom HTML logic here.  Does your DOM manipulation remove this button?, if so your in a world of pain.  What I normally do if add dynamic HTML that's not controlled by React, is create a `div`, and then `useRef` on this div.  Anything on the `divRef.current` is then left alone by React,  and you still get the `unmount` for the `div` container you created.

Comment: I'm afraid it's really not clear what your situation is. The code shown is a simple component that renders a button and handles clicks on it. If your real situation is more complicated than that, that code doesn't help you solve it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2):

> I have the following component and am attaching an eventlistner to the button present in it by DOM manipulation.

Normally that isn't how you handle events in React, see [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events). Not only is it unnecessarily complicated, but if you have more than one component, the unique ID may not be unique anymore.

Instead, use React to hook up the click handler:

```
function MyCustomComponent() {
    // Define the event handler
    function handleClick() {
        console.log("Button was clicked!");
    }

    // Hook it up with React
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's probably not necessary for a simple `button` element, but **if** you were passing the callback to a sub-component that may avoid re-rendering if its props don't change, you might add `useCallback` to that to make the click handler function stable. But with a simple `button` that's probably overkill.

---

In your question, you seem to be saying that your code may be working directly at the DOM level. If so, it's unclear how the component shown in the code relates to what you're really doing.

But **if** you were doing this with an element outside your React app's scope such that you can't handle events as above, then the usual way you'd handle this would be to keep a reference to the element so you can remove the handler from the same one you attached it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Define the event handler
    function handleClick() {
        console.log("Button was clicked!");
    }
    
    const element = document.getElementById("uniqueId"); // <−−−−−−−−−−−
    element.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // Cleanup: remove the event listener from the button
    return () => {
        element.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    //  ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    };
}, []);
```

Not only does that prevent a problem if `document.getElementById` returns `null` (because the element was removed), but it also prevents leaving the event handler on the element if its `id` is changed, or if it's temporarily detached from the document but then put back, etc. You're guaranteed you're always removing it from the element you added it to.

**If** you're sure that the `id` won't be changed (which is usually the case) and that the element won't be detached and reattached, you **could** just use a `null` guard instead via [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Define the event handler
    function handleClick() {
        console.log("Button was clicked!");
    }
    
    document.getElementById("uniqueId").addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // Cleanup: remove the event listener from the button
    return () => {
        document.getElementById("uniqueId")?.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    //                                     ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    };
}, []);
```

I'd usually go with the first approach, though.

But again, in the code shown in the answer, you wouldn't use an `id`, `getElementById`, or `addEventListener` at all.

---

Another option is to add and remove a listener on `body` rather than the specific element, using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) to determine whether to process the click:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Define the event handler
    function handleClick(event) {
        // Did the element pass through an element with our desired ID?
        const element = event.target.closest("#uniqueId"); // Note the #, that's a CSS selector
        if (element /* If we were doing this on anything other than `body`, we'd want: && event.currentTarget.contains(element)*/) {
            // Yes, handle it
            console.log("Button was clicked!");
        }
    }
    
    document.body.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // Cleanup: remove the event listener from the body
    return () => {
        document.body.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
}, []);
```

Note that this will use the then-current element with the given `id`, rather than the one that had that `id` at the outset. (Again, not usually an issue.)

Comment: Didn't read the question properly at first. I've fixed it now to cover doing this in React as well as the DOM, because [it's not clear what the OP's real situation is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77308544/cannot-access-dom-for-cleanup-in-the-react-useeffect-return-function-on-componen/77308564#comment136290412_77308544).

Comment: I am actually usign JS dom manipulation to populate the dom with HTML Nodes. And i cannot use useRef as i am serving pure JS file to a third party. And i am tryiing to removeEventListeners in the cleanup fucntion which i provide as well. But the clenup fucntion cannot query the dom as it has been removed.

Comment: @JalajYadav_Avesta - That doesn't make anything clearer. Hopefully, though, one of the techniques above is useful.

Comment: It makes no sense. when you unmount the `button`, there is no need to call `removeEventListener` anymore.

Comment: @xgqfrms - It totally depends on the details of what the OP is doing, which sadly aren't on offer.

Comment: An alternate solution might be to use event delegation, on `body` for example, where they can attach their handler and remove it on cleanup.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - Very good point, added!

Comment:  Main Question Here is >> When Unmounting a component, Does react run the useEffect cleanUp return function after clearing up the DOM Nodes for that component? 
@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @JalajYadav_Avesta - Yes, see [the documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect), specifically: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#:~:text=Your%20cleanup%20code%20runs%20one%20final%20time%20after%20your%20component%20is%20removed%20from%20the%20page (though frankly the docs used to be clearer, IMHO).